# How maven repository works

Tags: java, maven, selenium

I don't understand, how i must match class defination with maven repositories?
For example, I have a dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.webdriver</groupId>
  <artifactId>webdriver-chrome</artifactId>
  <version>0.9.7376</version>
</dependency>
```

I needed a `WebDriver` class, so I suggested that I should *import* `org.seleniumhq.webdriver`, but in reality it is in`org.openqa.selenium`. Is there a way to identify the package?

Comment: Artifact name is **not** related to Java package or class names. A maven artifact name is an arbitrary label.

Comment: You would look at documentation for whatever artifact you need in order to find its GAV (groupId, artifactId, version). Maven groupId != Java package although sometimes they are the same. For example [gson](https://github.com/google/gson) puts this information on its main github page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the artifact is in MavenCentral, you can use the class name search on https://search.maven.org/ Prefix the (qualified) class name with `c:` and get the desired artifacts.

Answer (score 1):

## Maven artifact name != Java class name

As Elliott Frisch commented on the Question, the artifact name (`<groupId>` & `<artifactID>`) used by Maven is arbitrary. That name need not be related directly to the names of the classes in the library downloaded by Maven and installed in your project.

The `import` statements in the classes you author in your `.java` files may be entirely different from the Maven artifact naming.

> Is there a way to identify the package?

Visit the web site for the library project in which you are interested. Most any such project will publicize a Maven `<dependency>` snippit. For example, [this page](http://www.h2database.com/html/cheatSheet.html) from the [H2 Database Engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H2_(DBMS)) project.

[image: Screenshot of a web browser window visiting the H2 Database Engine “Cheat Sheet” page listing a Maven dependency]

Maven finds the *H2 Database Engine* project’s library [in a Maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.h2database/h2), and downloads it, and installs it in your Java project. Then you add an `import` statement at the top of your `.java` file to identify the Java package of class you want to employ.

Notice the various naming, how in the Maven repository the artifact is named with a `<artifactId>` of  `h2` and `<groupId>` of `com.h2database`, while inside Java the `import` is `org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource`.

```java
package work.basil.example.h2.pstmt_query;

import org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource;  // ⬅ Import a class from the .jar file that Maven downloaded and installed via the repository artifact named `h2` with groupId of `com.h2database`.

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

…
```

To search Maven to find an artifact by the name of a class, see the [Answer by JF Meier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54506543/642706).